# Минимизация окон в ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Необходимо настроить минимизацию окон приложения, где она отсутствует. Вот в этом куске кода нет свойств minimized или minimizable, но в результирующем окне приложения есть рабочая кнопка "свернуть". В остальных случаях наследование задается так же через extend: 'Ext.window.Window', но нужных кнопок нет... Получилось вывести кнопку "свернуть" через minimizable, однако она не работает. Что я делаю не так?

```
Ext.define('TPL.view.resource.ListWindow', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias : 'widget.reslist',
title : '???????????????',
layout: 'fit',
autoShow: true,
maximizable: true,
maximized: true,
buttonAlign: 'left',
constrain: true,
// width: 850,
// height: 600,
closeAction: 'destroy',
autoScroll: true,
initComponent: function () {
Ext.apply(this, {
items: [
{
xtype: 'form',
//width: 850,
//height: 200,
border: false,
style: {
padding: '5px'
},
cls: 'x-plainform',
items:
```

Вот кусок, в который я вписала minimizable;:

```
Ext.define('TPL.view.documents.Create', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.document-create',
    title: 'Создание документа777',
    layout: 'fit',
    autoShow: true,
    constrain: true,
    maximizable: true,
    minimizable: true,
    config: {
        grid: null,
        departmentId: null,
        year: null
    },
    constructor: function (config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
        this.callParent(arguments);
```

так же пытаюсь добавить tools, но ничего не меняется:

```
 tools: [{
                type: 'minimizable',
                handler: function(){
                    //show minimizable here
                }
        }],
```

Answer (score 2):

Минимизация не работает 'Из коробки'. Данная кнопка только вызывает у окна событие `minimize`. Его необходимо обработать. [Пример](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tfj)

Comment: Имеет смысл добавить код из примера в сам вопрос.